# How can i mention AM/PM while inserting time value into a table in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I am trying to **insert values in time and column of table(doughnut_ratings) separately,** but it is giving following syntax error:

> *Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 65 Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.*

I am writing the following query, please suggest

```
create table doughnut_ratings
(
location varchar(30),
time time,
date date,
type char(30),
ratings int,
comments varchar(max),
)

insert into doughnut_ratings
values
('starbuzz coffee','7:43 am','4/23','cinnamon glazed',6,' too much price')
```

Comment: Considering that it's a literal string, why not use 24 hour format?

Comment: I don't have data in 24 hour format rather in am/pm format(12-hour). i will have to change every value in 24-hour format

Comment: Also, I have no problems with `'7:43 am'`. `TRY_CONVERT(time,'7:43 am')` returns `07:43:00.0000000`. [db<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=abe97744960fe3de99e43293a1b8e187) Have you actually tried inserting the values? if they're failing, it's not `'7:43 am'` that's failing.

Comment: Try_convert(time,....) worked. thanks, in date, i tried  try_convert(date,...) but it giving me null values.  I want it to take any default value like 0000 or 2020.

Comment: Can you tell us what SQL server you are using? @Larnu in MySQL I can not use these as dates, so it's probably different for different dbs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't the time (`'7:43 am'`), which can be converted without issue. `TRY_CONVERT(time,'7:43 am')` returns `07:43:00.0000000`. [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=abe97744960fe3de99e43293a1b8e187).

The problem is your "date": `'4/23'`. That isn't a `date`. A date is made up of the year, month and day, and it needs **all** of those. You need to use a format like `yyyyMMdd` or `yyyy-MM-dd`. If that date is this year, for example, it would be `'2020-04-23'`.

You need to fix your data, then you can `INSERT` it. `4/23` could represent many things. April 1923/April 2023; if so what day?. 23rd April; if so what year? 4th day of the 23rd year or 23rd day of the 4th year (no idea what that would be)?

Comment: i am inserting year manually, maybe this is the only way, can we take default values while creating table like default year to be 2000?

Comment: What date in 2000? 2000 isn't a date.

Comment: for example, i have many values which i need to insert in date column but i have just DD/MM like 29/09, 24/04 . while creating table can i make value of year to be default like .................create table xyz ( date date default year 2000), i dont know the syntax, i am just asking if its possible

Comment: It still doesn't make sense. The data in a single column should have **complete** meaning. Don't try to create some kind of convoluted shortcut just to try to avoid inserting a complete date into a column.

Comment: That isn't how SQL works, @satyamrastogi . A `DEFAULT` value is for when a value isn't inserted into a column. If you pass `'4/23'` to a `date` column the `INSERT` **will** fail; it isn't a date.